# Jenkins Groovy - Check if job is waiting for lockable resource

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to check in a pipeline groovy script if a job is currently waiting for a lockable resource to be free?

So the run of my job, for this example "master" (multibranch pipeline) is currently in this state:

```
Trying to acquire lock on [Label: <label-name>, Quantity: 1]
Found 0 available resource(s). Waiting for correct amount: 1.
[Label: <label-name>, Quantity: 1] is locked, waiting...
```

And I want to detect this from a different pipeline with a groovy script. I already tried to get some information with the following example script:

```
def resourceManager = org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.get()
def resourcesLockable = resourceManager.getResources().each{
  println(it)
  println(it.getBuildName())
  println("Locked: ${it.isLocked()}")
  println("Queued: ${it.isQueued()}")
  println("Reserved: ${it.isReserved()}")
}

def prId = "master"
def multibranch_project = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).findAll{it.getDisplayName().equals('<multibranch-project-name>')}.get(0)
def prJobList = multibranch_project .getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob).findAll{it.getDisplayName().trim().equals(prId.trim())}
def prJobRun = prJobList.get(0).builds
def resourcesFromBuild = resourceManager.getResourcesFromBuild(prJobRun.get(0))
println(resourcesFromBuild)
println(prJobRun.get(0).isBuilding())
println(prJobRun.get(0).isInProgress())
println(prJobRun.get(0).isLogUpdated())
println(prJobList.get(0).isInQueue())
```

The output would always state for all lockable resources (all currently locked, by other jobs):

- Locked: true
- Queued: false
- Reserved: false

And the output for the build "master" is:

- resourcesFromBuild: [] (empty list)
- isBuildiung: true
- isInProgress: true
- isLogUpdating: true
- isInQueue: false

So I cannot distinguish if the master is currently waiting for a lock, I can only see that all resources are locked, but not that master is waiting for a resource.

Example is based on this API documentation https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/lockable-resources/org/jenkins/plugins/lockableresources/LockableResourcesManager.html and https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/lockable-resources/org/jenkins/plugins/lockableresources/LockableResource.html

Maybe someone has an idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for now I found a hacky solution to identify a build waiting for a lockable resource.

I use the build log and make a string comparison of the last log line. If it equals "is locked, waiting...", the build waits for a resource.

This is the code I use:

```
Boolean waitingForAResource(build) {
  def logFile = build.getLogFile() //build = org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
  if (!logFile) {
    return false
  }
  def logLines = logFile.readLines()
  if (!logLines || logLines.size() == 0) {
    return false
  }

  def lastLine = logLines.takeRight(1).get(0)

  return lastLine.contains('is locked, waiting...')
}
```

I know that this could lead to false positives, but in my pipeline the string phrase I am matching is never used elsewhere.